# $\mathfrak{C}^{\infty}$ - Structures on Spheres

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Professor said there are 28  $\mathfrak{C}^{k}$ structures on  $\mathbb{S} ^7$ during lesson. Then I checked myself and came across with others as: 992 for $\mathbb{S} ^{11} $ or just 1 for $\mathbb{S} ^{12} $. How can we calculate the number of structures? [image]

Comment: I suspect that this is too difficult a problem for a detailed answer here. The keyword to search for is exotic spheres. See for example the classification section in the wikipedia page [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_sphere).

Comment: Note also that there are many, many references and external links on Wiki's "exotic sphere" page (the page [differential structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_structure#Differential_structures_on_spheres_of_dimension_1_to_20) that the OP found has minimal references.)  I did a quick edit on the Wiki article to make the link more explicit.

Comment: Is a $\mathfrak{C}^{k}$  structure the same thing as a $C^k$ structure?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I think the book which I follow uses different notation.

Comment: This is a major and very difficult question. There is no general formula, and it is not even known if all sufficiently high dimensional spheres always have exotic smooth structures. I wrote an answer about the difficult algebraic topology involved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1609522/98602).