# Are there (known to be) exotic spheres in arbitrarily high even dimension?

Tags: algebraic-topology, reference-request, differential-topology

I was wondering if there are infinitely many even positive integers $2k$ for which there exists an exotic sphere of dimension $2k$. Here by an "exotic sphere" of dimension $n$ we mean a smooth manifold homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic to the standard $n$-sphere.

The odd-dimensional case is described in e.g. [this Stackexchange post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1609328/the-only-odd-dimensional-spheres-with-a-unique-smooth-structure-are-s1-s3): for every odd number $>61$ there is an exotic sphere of that dimension.

Would anyone know of any sources/references discussing the even-dimensional case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is true. For $n>8$ there exist exotic $n$-spheres if $n$ is congruent modulo 192 to one of 2, 6, 8, 10, 14, 18, 20, 22, 26, 28, 32, 34, 40, 42, 46, 50, 52, 54, 58, 60, 66, 68,
70, 74, 80, 82, 90, 98, 100, 102, 104, 106, 110, 114, 116, 118, 122, 124, 128,
130, 136, 138, 142, 146, 148, 150, 154, 156, 162, 164, 170, 178, 186.

See Corollary 1.5 of  "The 2-primary Hurewicz image of tmf" by Behrens, Mahowald, Quigley.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and the reference suggestion!

Comment: This statement seems so random... amazing!

Comment: I'd be super interested if someone could comment (or if Connor could edit) to just briefly give an idea of what $192$ is in this story. It's not a number that "feels significant" to me, so I'm curious to see why it comes up. Is it $8\times 24$, where $24$ has its usual connexion to the Leech lattice and so on?

Comment: @CaptainLama My understanding is that there is a quotient group of the stable homotopy groups of spheres called $\mathrm{coker}(J)$ which was shown (with a few exceptions related to the Kervaire invariant) to be in bijection with the exotic spheres. To produce nontrivial elements of  $\mathrm{coker}(J)$, the authors found elements in the spectrum $\mathrm{tmf}$ which were in the image of the Hurewicz map and so had to come from the stable homotopy groups of spheres. The 2-torsion of $\pi_*(\mathrm{tmf})$ is 192 periodic, hence the periodicity.

Comment: Let $D$ be [the set](https://oeis.org/A191783) of integers (like $1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 12, 56, 61$) for which there are _no_ exotic spheres of that dimension. Is $D$ expected to be finite?

Comment: Ah, I see now that in the reference _Guozhen Wang and Zhouli Xu, The triviality of the 61-stem in the stable homotopy groups of spheres, Annals of Mathematics, 186 (2017), 501-580_ to which there are links in the OEIS entry I included in my previous comment, they have a Conjecture 1.17 that says that 61 is the last dimension for which the sphere has a unique smooth structure. (This is the same reference which was the basis for the Math Stack Exchange thread that the asker cites as the inspiration for this one.)